# Stopping an animated DrawLine and starting a new one

Tags: java, swing, animation, time, line

Edit : Here is the full code. After each actionPerformed I need to change the values for x1,y1,x2,y2, and t before executing the repain(). Is there a simple way this can be done? I've only taken one basic class in Java so try to keep it at a beginner level.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*; 

public class Line {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);;
        frame.add(new DrawLine(0,0,0,0));
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);  
      }
    });  
  } 
}

class DrawLine extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

  int x1;
  int y1;
  int x2;
  int y2;
  int i=100;
  int j=50;
  int t=1000;
  Timer time = new Timer(t, (ActionListener) this);

  public DrawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
    time.start();
  }

  public void animateLine(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    x2=x2+i;
    y2=y2+j;
    time.stop();
    time.start();
    repaint();
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics newG) {
    super.paintComponent(newG);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)newG;
    animateLine(g2d);
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 3) `time.stop();` (is how to stop the animation).

Comment: Possible suggestions: draw the animated line to the JPanel's paintComponent method override (which you're not showing), and draw the completed line to a BufferedImage which is also drawn in paintComponent. And yeah, edit your code so that it's readable. It's not considered good form to force folks here to read difficult to read code.

Comment: My apologies, it wasn't showing as "code" on here if each line was indented 4 spaces.

Comment: Stop making apologies and follow my suggestion to post an MCVE.

Comment: Where do I insert the stop command and how would I call a new line? Can this all be done within the actionPerformed?

Comment: Yes, it can be done within actionPerformed as long as you put some logic into that method including if conditions. But I too second @AndrewThompson's recommendation, please post your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can more easily study and run your code.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you have two components drawing your line, the dynamic and the static. The dynamic component is the line that is in the process of being animated, and for that, you should do your drawing within the JPanel's paintComponent method. Once that line has been completely drawn, then it should be drawn more permanently onto a BufferedImage, which represents the static portion of your image, which is also drawn in paintComponent. The paintComponent could look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super. paintComponent(g);

    // here convert g to Graphics2D and set rendering hints
    // to smooth the line via anti-aliasing

    if (bufferedImg != null) {
        g.drawImage(bufferedImg, 0, 0, null);
    }
    // a boolean check
    if (drawingLine) {
        g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    }
}
```

Then within your Timer's actionListener you would need if conditions:

- One would identify when the current line is done drawing, and if not, the extend this line.
- If so, then draw the current line to the BufferedImage
- And then start the new line, if the program logic dictates that this should occur.

For e.g.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (lineJustNowCompleted) {
        drawLineToBufferedImage();
    } else if (stillDrawingLine) {
        incrementLineEndPoints();
    } 
    repaint();

}
```

Of course the devil will be in the details, and if you still need help, you'll need to provide those details and more code, preferably an MCVE.

Comment: I see what you're getting at here. I posted the full code but every time I modify the values for x1 and y1 to have the new line start at the position the previous line ended the animation doesn't run.

Comment: @caine1337: you have no logic code within actionPerformed that tests when the line should end and a new one should begin, and that's what you need. Only you at present know what those triggers should be.